# Datepicker calendar does not show update value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a datepicker control like below

```
<div class="input-group date dvFromDate" data-date-autoclose="true" data-auto-close="true">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
        CssClass="form-control input-append datepicker nonEditable"
        onblur="javascript:ValidateFromDate(this,'')"></asp:TextBox>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Using javascript I am changing date like

```
  var startDate= new Date();
  $('.dvFromDate').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
```

The textbox show update value, but the calendar when open , show old date. Let say while page load I had set date to '21/06/2018'. After soem operation, i updated date to '25/06/2018'. Calendar shows 21/06/2018 when opened.

Comment: set the element value date as well, $('.dvFromDate').val(fmtStartDate) where fmtStartdate is your formated value of the new Date()

Comment: Tried both, but no luck                                                        $('#txtDateFrom').val(startDate);
$('.dvFromDate').val(startDate);

Comment: so you have both lines of code? First: $('.dvFromDate').val(fmtStartDate) and then $('.dvFromDate').datepicker('setDate', startDate); fmtStartDate should look like this '25/06/2018'

Comment: Yes, formaat is ok.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I can not reproduce the bug. [The code](https://jsfiddle.net/koryukov/nkoy5472/) works fine. Could you clarify the problem statement?